# getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException from hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

Why i'm getting this error even while i'm running just a hello program(in separate java project).
actually this error coming from hibernate, but can any one explain me what is the issue and where it is and how to fix it.

Please find my hibernate code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Student_Info student_Info = new Student_Info();

    student_Info.setName("xyz");
    student_Info.setRollNo(101);
    student_Info.setLastName("kumar");
    student_Info.setRecordUpdatedDate(new Date());
    student_Info.setRecordUpdatedTime(new Date());
    student_Info.setRecordUpdatedOn(new Date());
    student_Info.setIsActive(false);
    student_Info.setDescription("hi this is xyz.");

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(student_Info);
        transaction.commit();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        if (transaction != null)
            transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();                            //close session
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();  //close sessionFactory
    }
}
```

Please find code of Student_Info

```
@Entity @Table(name="student")
```

public class Student_Info {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int rollNo;

private String name;

@Transient
@Column(name="lastName", nullable=false)
private String lastName;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date recordUpdatedDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date recordUpdatedTime;

private Date recordUpdatedOn;

private Boolean isActive;

@Lob
private String description;

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public Boolean getIsActive() {
    return isActive;
}
public void setIsActive(Boolean isActive) {
    this.isActive = isActive;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getRollNo() {
    return rollNo;
}
public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
    this.rollNo = rollNo;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Date getRecordUpdatedDate() {
    return recordUpdatedDate;
}
public void setRecordUpdatedDate(Date recordUpdatedDate) {
    this.recordUpdatedDate = recordUpdatedDate;
}
public Date getRecordUpdatedTime() {
    return recordUpdatedTime;
}
public void setRecordUpdatedTime(Date recordUpdatedTime) {
    this.recordUpdatedTime = recordUpdatedTime;
}
public Date getRecordUpdatedOn() {
    return recordUpdatedOn;
}
public void setRecordUpdatedOn(Date recordUpdatedOn) {
    this.recordUpdatedOn = recordUpdatedOn;
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Something at line 72 in your code is `null` - which is line 72 and what might be null?

Comment: Which line is line 72?

Comment: this code is ending on line 39 actually. That's why i'm also not getting why it showing me line 72.

Comment: Click error which is as blue line , it will show you the line.

Comment: when i run any program then this error comes on the previously run program and and you know that console clears the previous logs.

Comment: after clicking on blue line: "72 is not a valid line number in com.student.Main

Comment: add codes of student class to your questions.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: I added answer , can you try?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are problem with transaction. Can you change transaction code instead of yours.

```
Transaction transObj = null;
Session sessionObj = null;
try {
    sessionObj = HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory().openSession();
    transObj = sessionObj.beginTransaction();
    transObj.commit();
} catch (HibernateException exObj) {
    if(transObj!=null){
        transObj.rollback();
    }
    exObj.printStackTrace(); 
} finally {
    sessionObj.close(); 
}
```

Because you are using

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
```

but you dont have any `currentSession`. So this will throw `NullPointerException` when `session.beginTransaction()`; calls. In my solution session is starting from `BuildSessionFactory` .